# SQLAlchemy declarative syntax with autoload (reflection) in Pylons

Tags: python, reflection, sqlalchemy, pylons, declarative

I would like to use autoload to use an existings database. I know how to do it without declarative syntax (model/_*init*_.py):

```
def init_model(engine):
    """Call me before using any of the tables or classes in the model"""
    t_events = Table('events', Base.metadata, schema='events', autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    orm.mapper(Event, t_events)

    Session.configure(bind=engine)  

class Event(object):
    pass
```

This works fine, but I would like to use declarative syntax:

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'events', 'autoload': True}
```

Unfortunately, this way I get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData. Pass an engine to the Table via autoload_with=<someengine>, or associate the MetaData with an engine via metadata.bind=<someengine>

The problem here is that I don't know where to get the engine from (to use it in autoload_with) at the stage of importing the model (it's available in init_model()). I tried adding

```
meta.Base.metadata.bind(engine)
```

to environment.py but it doesn't work. Anyone has found some elegant solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out. The solution is to declare the model objects outside the `model/__init__.py`. I concluded that `__init__.py` gets imported as the first file when importing something from a module (in this case `model`) and this causes problems because the model objects are declared before `init_model()` is called.

To avoid this I created a new file in the `model` module, e.g. `objects.py`. I then declared all my model objects (like `Event`) in this file.

Then, I can import my models like this:

```
from PRJ.model.objects import Event
```

Furthermore, to avoid specifying `autoload-with` for each table, I added this line at the end of `init_model()`:

```
Base.metadata.bind = engine
```

This way I can declare my model objects with no boilerplate code, like this:

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'events', 'autoload': True}

    event_identifiers = relationship(EventIdentifier)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Event(%s)>" % self.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this using orm module.

```
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

Base.metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
```

Accessing tables manually or through loop or whatever:

```
Base.metadata.sorted_tables
```

Might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData,create_engine,Table
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:********@localhost/db_name')

metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

rivers = Table('rivers',metadata,autoload=True,auto_load_with=engine)

from sqlalchemy import select

s = select([rivers]).limit(5)
engine.execute(s).fetchall()
```

worked for me. I was getting the error because of not specifying bind when creating `MetaData()` object.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Using SQLAlchemy with Pylons tutorial](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Using+SQLAlchemy+with+Pylons#UsingSQLAlchemywithPylons-Mainmodelmodule) on how to bind metadata to the engine in the `init_model` function.

If the `meta.Base.metadata.bind(engine)` statement successfully binds your model metadata to the engine, you should be able to perform this initialization in your own `init_model` function. I guess you didn't mean to skip the metadata binding in this function, did you?

Comment: This is so not up-to-date. You are talking about this line: `meta.engine = engine`, right? Pylons 1.0 doesn't even have any `engine` variable in the `meta` module... Not to mention that when this tutorial was written, the declarative syntax didn't exist.

Comment: You're right but I mean binding metadata to the engine in `init_model`, in spite of differences in implementation with latest versions. You get the idea. Doesn't it work if you do `Base.metadata.bind(engine)` in `init_model`? You can also try `Base.metadata.bind = engine` in `init_model` as suggested by the error message you're getting.

Comment: It doesn't work because init_model() is called after the models are already created. The models are created when doing `from PRJ.model import init_model` (it imports something from the module and thus all the module is executed), i.e. before calling init_model().

Comment: I see you figured it out. Sorry if I didn't make myself perfectly clear from the beginning. I didn't know you were declaring model classes in your `model/__init__.py` so I couldn't see why you couldn't call `init_model` before declaring model classes.

Comment: I see, no problem, maybe I didn't put it clear enough. Thanks for answering anyway.