# Using repoze.what with declarative syntax in pylons

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm writing an application in Pylons and I want to add an authorization scheme. I've chosen repoze.what. I followed the tutorial from Pylons cookbook:

http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Authorization+with+repoze.what

The problem is that in `lib/auth.py` I need to include models for User, Group and Permission. Using declarative base in model, it gives me an error when I want to deploy:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData.
Pass an engine to the Table via autoload_with=<someengine>, or associate the MetaData
with an engine via metadata.bind=<someengine>
```

I found similar problem here:

[SQLAlchemy declarative syntax with autoload (reflection) in Pylons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526498/sqlalchemy-declarative-syntax-with-autoload-reflection-in-pylons)

I have all the models for authorization declared in a separate file from `__init__.py`. I also followed all indications from above question but there is still something wrong.
Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the model `__init__.py` you need to bind the engine to the session.

```
def init_model(engine):
    """Call me before using any of the tables or classes in the model"""
    ## Reflected tables must be defined and mapped here
    #global reflected_table
    #reflected_table = sa.Table("Reflected", meta.metadata, autoload=True,
    #                           autoload_with=engine)
    #orm.mapper(Reflected, reflected_table)

    session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True, autocommit=False)
    meta.metadata.bind = engine
    meta.engine = engine
    meta.Session = orm.scoped_session(session)
```

Resources:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons_framework/dev/advanced_models.html

Comment: This doesn't work. My init_model() looks like this:

    `def init_model(engine):
        """Call me before using any of the tables or classes in the model"""
        Session.configure(bind=engine)
        meta.engine = engine
        Base.metadata.bind = engine`

I forgot to point out that repoze acts as a middleware. In middleware.py I include a method which includes some models of my application (for authorization) and then models are loaded before init_model() is invoked, as I understand. This creates the conflict.

Comment: I think what you are missing are the autoload and autoload_with args when loading your reflected tables i.e Table('some_table', meta, autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I just create an engine in the module that contains models for authorization and I bind it to the metadata. I have no idea why init_model does not do this on its own. So this is not a problem of declarative syntax. Sorry for inconvenience.